# Msg 205, Level 16, State 1,All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must have an equal number of expressions

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to select random rows from different tables using `order by newid()` and union the results together, but I am getting an error
What am I doing wrong?

```
create procedure [dbo].[genrate_Exame] 
    @course_id int
as 
    if @course_id = 600
    begin
        select top(7) 
            C.C#_Mcq_Id,
            C.C#_MCQ_Question,
            C.C#_Choices, 
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_MCQ C
          
        union all

        select top(3) 
            T.C#_T_F_Id,
            T.C#_T_F_Q,
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_T_F T
        order by NEWID()
     end
     else if (@course_id = 500)
     begin 
         select top(7)
             Q.SQl_Mcq_id,
             Q.SQl_MCQ_Question,
             Q.SQl_Choices,
             null as [no_question]
         from SQl_MCQ Q
             
         union all

         select top(3)
             QT.SQl_T_F_Id,
             QT.SQl_T_F_Q, 
             null as [no_question]
         from 
             SQl_T_F QT
         order by 
             NEWID()
    end
```

Comment: The error message is self-explanatory: any union operation must have select statements which include the same _number_ and _type_ of columns.  Your query is not doing this, hence the error.

Comment: I know that the message is self-explanatory but i don't know anther solution to solve this problem without `union` if you know told me

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `UNION` and `UNION ALL`, below conditions must be met.[Read about UNION on MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/set-operators-union-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

> The following are basic rules for combining the result sets of two
> queries by using UNION:
>
> The number and the order of the columns must be the same in all
> queries.
>
> The data types must be compatible.

In your case, you are not having equal number of expressions:

```sql
-- 4 columns here
 select top(7) 
            C.C#_Mcq_Id,
            C.C#_MCQ_Question,
            C.C#_Choices, 
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_MCQ C
          
        union all
-- 3 columns here
        select top(3) 
            T.C#_T_F_Id,
            T.C#_T_F_Q,
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_T_F T
```

Also, if you want to randomly get values, you have apply `ORDER BY NEWID()` in both parts of SELECT query, not just outside.

```sql
SELECT * FROM
(
 select top(7) 
            C.C#_Mcq_Id,
            C.C#_MCQ_Question,
            C.C#_Choices, 
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_MCQ C
ORDER BY NEWID()
) as t1
union all
SELECT * FROM 
(
 select top(3) 
            T.C#_T_F_Id,
            T.C#_T_F_Q,
            null as [C#_Choices]
            null as [no_question]
        from C#_T_F T
ORDER BY NEWID()
) as t2
```

Comment: The order by would have to be outside the union, which is implied if its put after the last one. I believe your's would throw and error.

Comment: @TomC, great catch. I tested and modified the query. thanks for your extra review